# Is there a way of converting a fd into a FILE* or is there a mkstemp version that returns a FILE*?

Tags: c, file, tmp

Is there a way of "converting" a fd into a FILE* or is there a mkstemp version that returns a FILE*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fdopen()` is the function you are looking for.